# Checkstyle – ignore Javadoc while checking duplication

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle to check violation in my code. One of the module in my configuration is about duplicate code. Since I am using StrictDuplicateCode I get violation on duplication for javaDoc as well.

Can anyone guide me to achieve my goal?

In the meantime, I tried following BUT it doesn’t work:

To suppress duplication with java doc I created a separate xml file (JavaDocSup.xml) with following content

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
    <suppressions>
    <suppress checks="JavadocStyleCheck"
              files="SomeClass.java"
    />
    </suppressions>
```

Then I added following code in my main configuration file. Following is the code for my config file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

    <module name="Checker">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="MethodLength">
          <property name="max" value="50"/>
       </module>
    <module name="ParameterNumber">
      <property name="max" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="CyclomaticComplexity"/>
     </module>
  <module name="StrictDuplicateCode">
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
  </module>
   <module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${samedir}/JavaDocSup.xml"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

When I run the checkstyle on my code, it still detects the duplicate lines in the Java doc. 
Is the suppress checks="JavadocStyleCheck” is correct?
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The different checks are normally independent of each other. So suppressing some *JavadocStyle* issues will not have any effect on the *StrictDuplicateCode* check. You will need to request a new option to *StrictDuplicateCode*.

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle's *StrictDuplicateCode* is found to be inefficient, hence it's [thrown away](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/523) (since [Checkstyle 6.2](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.2)).  Try using other tools like PMD's [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/cpd.html), etc.

If you want to stick to current Checkstyle version, you can try adding `<property name="min" value="20"/>` to throw the violation only if at least 20 lines are matching.

(Some clone detection tools are mentioned under Tools section in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Duplicate_code&oldid=522795578))